# Error while installing pyqt (v4.8) on Mac

Tags: python, ruby, macos, pyqt, homebrew

I tried "brew install pyqt" after checking
[How to install PyQt on Mac OS X 10.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583092/how-to-install-pyqt-on-mac-os-x-10-6) and a bunch of blogsites. Specifially,

```
> brew install qt --with-developer --env=std
```

But it failed with this error -

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see  invocation)
make[2]: *** [../../lib/QtCore.framework/QtCore] Error 1
make[1]: *** [release] Error 2
make: *** [sub-corelib-make_default-ordered] Error 2

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:353:in `open_http': 422 Unprocessable Entity (GitHub::Error)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:709:in `buffer_open'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:210:in `block in open_loop'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:208:in `catch'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:208:in `open_loop'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:149:in `open_uri'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:689:in `open'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:30:in `open'
from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/utils.rb:343:in `open'
from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/utils.rb:373:in `issues_matching'
from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/utils.rb:401:in `issues_for_formula'
from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/exceptions.rb:145:in `fetch_issues'
from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/exceptions.rb:141:in `issues'
from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/exceptions.rb:184:in `dump'
from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:162:in `rescue in <main>'
from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:65:in `<main>'
```

Can someone please help me out? I see that there's a problem on the open-uri.rb module, but I have almost no experience with Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

updating homebrew got rid of this error for me:

```
brew update
```